# How do I move list items?

Tags: jquery

I have a normal unordered list

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on any of the list items it should appear 2nd in the list, if possible animate to second position.

I know an easy solution for this would to relatively position the UL and absolutely position the LIs and set the top position, but this not possible because of the way the markup is written.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This does everything but the animation:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.insertAfter($this.siblings(':eq(0)'));
});
```

When you click on a list item, it will insert it after the first item in the `<ul>`, i.e. the second position in the list.

Furthermore, you could animate this in various ways. Here's one:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        callback = function() {
            $this.insertAfter($this.siblings(':eq(0)'));
        };
    $this.slideUp(500, callback).slideDown(500);
});
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JrJck/).

Comment: Works a treat! Do you know if its even possible to animates these or this something I should move on from?

Comment: It depends on how you want to animate it. I updated my answer with a basic animation example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at nth selector here http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` to the unordered list (`<ul id="list">`), and add it after the second child.

```
$('#list li').click(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter("#list li:nth-child(1)");
});
```

This only works for elements after the first, but an example is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KgrS/3/).