# jQuery doesn't work when move list item

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to move the list item when click on them, and I followed the code of this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715443/how-do-i-move-list-items#comment10848701_8715500). And it did work on JSfiddle, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u5jr8f2q/).

But when I move this code into html file, it doesn't work. The content of the whole file is listed below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test the jQuery cycle</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.simple li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.insertBefore($this.siblings('.simple li:nth-child(1)'));
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.for-list li{
    float:left; width:60px;
    }
.for-list{
    list-style-type:none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="simple for-list">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't find out What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run this in the `<head>`:

```
$('.simple li').click(function() {
```

No such item exists yet (in fact, no elements exist at all). So the handler is attached to *nothing*. It won't affect `.simple li` items created later on.

You can:

1. Move that script block to the end of the body
2. Wrap it in `$(document).ready(...)`, so it runs *after* the various elements actually exist
3. Use on `on` handler instead, like `$(document).on('click', '.simple li', function() ...)`

```css
.for-list li{
    float:left; width:60px;
    }
.for-list{
    list-style-type:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="simple for-list">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
  
<!-- set the handler *after* creating the elements -->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.simple li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.insertBefore($this.siblings('.simple li:nth-child(1)'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the $(document).ready(). This way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.simple li').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.insertBefore($this.siblings('.simple li:nth-child(1)'));
    });
});
```